# Cannot assign to read only property 'detachedCallback' of object '#'

Tags: angular, aframe

I installed [A-Frame](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe) by

```
npm install aframe --save.
```

When I use:

```
import 'aframe';  // or use: require 'aframe';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <a-scene></a-scene>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I got the error:

> zone.js:1046Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property
>   'detachedCallback' of object '#'

I checked this [Angular_VRDemo](https://github.com/brakmic/Angular_VRDemo), but still did not figure out myself.

Comment: I guess you should load this library outside zonejs http://take.ms/tR0Sh and add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to `schemas` property of your root angular2 module

Comment: @yurzui yeah, this way works! would u mind posting on answer, so i can accept? BTW, is it possible to use NPM package instead of loading by `<script></script>` in the header?

Comment: Just put it before zonejs http://take.ms/CtAMX

Comment: @yurzui thanks, it is working perfect! can u move to answer so i can accpet? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it because `aframe` library doesn't implement some properties (like `detachedCallback` and other) by creation custom element.
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.3.1/src/core/a-assets.js#L13-L73

zonejs has overrided version of `document.registerElement` that requires all properties so it breaks library loading (https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/v0.6.17/dist/zone.js#L1151-L1170).

As workaround you can load this library before  zonejs